# How to play only live videos from youtube channel in my android app?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am making an application where I need to play current live video from my youtube channel. Before i was using webview with iframe with this code :

```
String frameVideo = "<html><body>Youtube video .. " +
            "<br> <iframe width=\"480\" height=\"290\" " +
            "src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=MY_CHANNEL_ID\" " +
            "frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"></iframe></body></html>";

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

It was working good.

Now I have started to use Youtube api. Its works better, It can play simple video, but I dont know how to get current live stream?

вот мой код Youtube api:

```
youTubePlayerView.initialize(getString(R.string.youtube_api_key),this);

}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    if (!b)
    {
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo("shN7zv0Ffuw");  //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shN7zv0Ffuw
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1)
    {
        getYoutubePlayerProvider().initialize(getString(R.string.youtube_api_key),this);
    }
}

private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYoutubePlayerProvider() {
    return youTubePlayerView;
}
```

}

How can i load this url : `"https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=MY_CHANNEL_ID\"` by using
youtube player?

Comment: a place to start searching: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player

Comment: Sir , I didnt find there(